# hasAndBelongsToMany not pulling data for associationForeignKey

Tags: php, cakephp

In my CakePHP application I have users that are able to be friends with other users.

This is done with a `users` table and a `friends_users` table which has the following columns: `id, user_id, friend_id, status` for the relationship.

So if user id 1 is friends with user id 2 it would have 1 in the user_id and 2 in friend_id columns

And the model for User looks like:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Friend'=>array(
            'className'              => 'User',
            'joinTable'              => 'friends_users',
            'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'friend_id'
        )
    );
```

When viewing User 1 it works fine and shows User 2 as a friend. BUT when viewing User 2 it does not show User 1 as a friend... So it's not fulling the data when viewed in reverse!

Here is the method I use to list the friends for a user:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array( 
                    'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
                    'contain'=>'Profile'
                ));

        $friends = $this->User->find('first', 
            array(
                'conditions'=>array(
                   'User.id'=>$user['User']['id']
                ),
                'contain'=>array(
                    'Profile',
                    'Friend'=>array(
                        'Profile',
                        'conditions'=>array(
                            'FriendsUser.status'=>1
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $this->set('friends', $friends);
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I have looked through the docs but all seems fine to me.

**Ideally I'd like to fix my code rather than be pointed to some other resource!**

Queries on the page: http://pastebin.com/zQnBVM2X

Comment: What queries does your code generate? Could you post the content of `friends_users` table related to those queries? What associations has Friends model and why you do not use it?

Comment: There is no Friends model! The model is virtual inside the User model.

Comment: That is clear. Could you answer the first 2 questions too?

Comment: I don't understand your request. Could you clarify?

Comment: 1. Set debug of your application to 2, copy queries from the bottom of you page and paste them here. 2. Copy your `friends_users` table (or part of it) and paste it here.

Comment: Added the queries above in a paste. The table is as described above!

Comment: It is good that you described the table. But if we would know the content of that table (or part of it related to the queries you posted) it would be much easier to locate the source of your problem. What values are in the table?

Comment: `id = 1, user_id = 6, friend_id = 8, status = 1`

Answer (score 2):

When you retrieve friends for user #6 you will get friend #8. When you retrieve friends for user #8 you should receive nothing because there are no records for user #8 in your `friends_users` table. So, either you need to insert additional data in `friends_users` table (`user_id = 8, friend_id = 6`) or you need to create `Friend` model (using no table) and retrieve users via `Friend`. That is mental gymnastics - you need to realize that User is Friend and Friend is User.

```
        $friends = $this->User->Friend->find('first', 
            array(
                'conditions'=>array(
                   'Friend.id'=>$id // user id whose friends you need to find
                ),
                'contain'=>array(
                    'Profile',
                    'User'=>array( // here you will get friends
                        'Profile',
                        'conditions'=>array(
                            'FriendsUser.status'=>1
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: He doesn't need to do either of those. The associations will suffice

Comment: There are many ways to do the job but when you have too many relations CakePHP generates too many queries.

Comment: so use containable to limit that

Comment: @bancer Can you show what would be in this new Friend model and what the relationship settings I would need to do in the User model to get them talking to each other. Thanks.

Comment: You would need to set `useTable` to false in Friend model - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable. HABTM relationships in User and Friend should be setup as per cookbook, nothing special - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm, like if you would set up habtm beetween User and Group.

Comment: Is this correct then? http://pastebin.com/PSyz7DyM If you could amend any mistakes I have made, that'd be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Okay tried that and when I do a debug on $friends I just get false instead of the array of data I would normally expect! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem, I was faced with this same issue a few years ago when I was building a dating site.

What you need to do is have (in my case) 4 sets of relations:

- Forward relations
- Forward relations (unapproved friendships)
- Backward relations
- Backward relations (unapproved friendships)

This will ensure you pull all necessary data, use `containable` wherever possible.

```php
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'ForwardRelation' => array(
        'className'  => 'User',
        'joinTable'  => 'friends_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => array('approved' => '1'),
        'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id',
        ),
    'ForwardRelationUn' => array(
       'className'  => 'User',
        'joinTable'  => 'friends_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => array('approved' => '0'),
        'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id'
        ),
    'BackRelation' => array(
        'className'  => 'User',
        'joinTable'  => 'friends_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'friend_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => array('approved' => 1)
        ),
    'BackRelationUn' => array(
        'className'  => 'User',
        'joinTable'  => 'friends_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'friend_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => array('approved' => '0')
    )
);
```

Add a behavior with some `afterFind()` magic, and you will be golden!

This is my function to find friends:

```php
function getFriends( $userid, $search = null ) {

    $Friends    = ClassRegistry::init( 'FriendsUser' );

    $Friends->bindModel( 
        array(
            'belongsTo' => array(
                'User' => array(
                    'className' => 'User',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
                ),
                'Friend' => array(
                    'className' => 'User',
                    'foreignKey' => 'friend_id'
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    $data = $Friends->find( 
        'all', 
        array( 
            'fields' => array( 
                'DISTINCT FriendsUser.friend_id', 
                'FriendsUser.user_id',
                'FriendsUser.approved',
                'User.id', 
                'User.username', 
                'Friend.id', 
                'Friend.username'
                ), 
            'conditions' => array(
                 'AND' => array(
                     'OR' => array( 
                        'Friend.username LIKE' => '%' . $search . '%',
                        'User.username LIKE' => '%' . $search . '%'
                        )
                    )
                ),
            'contain' => array(
                'User', 
                'Friend'
                ),
            'order' => array( 'User.username ASC', 'FriendsUser.approved DESC' )
        ) 
    );


    $friendlist = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach ( $data as $datum ) {

        foreach ( $datum as $key => $value ) {

            if ( in_array( $key, array( 'User', 'Friend' ) ) ) {

                if ( $value['id'] == $userid ) {
                    $friendlist[$i]['Me'] = $value;
                } else {
                    $friendlist[$i]['Friend']           = $value;
                }

            }
        }

        $i++;

    }

    $matches = array();

    foreach ( $friendlist as $friend ) {

        if ( stripos( $friend['Friend']['username'], $search ) !== false )
            $matches[ $friend['Friend']['id'] ] = $friend['Friend']['username'];

    }

    asort( $matches );

    $i = 0;

    $newmatches = array();

    foreach ( $matches as $key => $match ) {
        $newmatches[$i]['Tag']['caption']   = $match;
        $newmatches[$i]['Tag']['value']     = $key; 
        $newmatches[$i]['Tag']['image']     = $this->getProfileImage( $key );

        $i++;       
    }

    return $newmatches;

}
```

Comment: This sounds interesting! But could you show more info regarding how to use this? e.g. the afterFind and how I'd use that inside my method. Thanks.

Comment: Updated with my `getFriends()` function

Comment: How your declared associations correspond to your find method? You bind models manually and I don't see the reason why should you declare those associations.

Comment: I am binding a hasMany relationship.